# converting DisparityImage message to PointCloud2

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, libopencv, stere-image-proc, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to convert a `DisparityImage` message to a `PointCloud2` messages such that each pixel disparity value is now a x, y, z value of a point in space. The other information that comes as part of the `DisparityImage` message are the focal length, max disparity and baseline. I know how to calculate the z value using them but I'm not sure what the equation is for x and y?

I was looking at this opencv function `reprojectImageTo3D()` but that needs the `Q` perspective transformation matrix. How should I calculate that?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286369/converting-disparityimage-message-to-pointcloud2/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) nodelet. That should do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-03-23**:
Yeah but I would rather just construct the `Q` matrix myself and make the opencv call. I guess what I'm asking is, does the `DisparityImage` message have enough information to make the Q matrix? I found the equations here but don't have required fields...

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-03-23**:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/4379/from-3d-point-cloud-to-disparity-map/

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-03-23**:
Probably not... The page you linked says "Combines a rectified color image and disparity image to produce a point cloud" so maybe the `image_rect` has the remainder of the information, that's a bummer. I would've thought the disparity message should come with all required values.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-03-23**:
Most of the remaining information should come from the `camera_info` topics.